# How do I pass a list of lists as @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, spring-mvc

**Desired request:**

```
http://localhost:8080/values?input=[["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"],["abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd"]]
```

I would love to be able to pass the URL in some way using brackets.

However **if it is not possible**, how do I still pass the list of lists ?

**My controller path:**

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/values/")
public String getValues(@RequestParam List<List<@Size(min=4, max=4)String>> input) {
    return input.get(0).get(2);
}
```

which should return `ccc`.

Comment: Why do you need having such a complicated structure(list of list of string) in the request param?

Comment: That's not a very GET looking request. Nor can you put a validation annotation inside a generic type declaration like `List<@Size(min=4, max=4)String>`, so in any case your approach couldn't work.

Comment: @Malathi The 4 variables in the inner list will be used for calculation. And will return 1 value. Thus, I will get a list of this new variable as output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a good way to do this job. Instead you can pass them as request parameter and and receive them from hashMap. But since you are passing list of lists, so it would be convenient to pass them in request body. To do that you have to create a request POJO class following these steps:

```
public class ListRequest{
    private List<List<String>> inputList;
    //generate getter, setter for it
}
```

Now, change in your controller, replace `GET` method with `POST`:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/values/")
    public String getValues(@RequestBody ListRequest input) {
         List<List<String>> yourData=input;
         System.out.println(yourData);
        //operate on your data as you wish
        return input.get(0).get(2);
    }
```

Comment: How would the get request look in this case?

Comment: I forgot to mention, get is not here anyway, the request is transformed into POST method. Moreover, you have to  send data in requestBody, not as you have shown in your question

Comment: Yes. This is the best solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a Pojo class with a list of list as field. 
Send the values in the request body and use a post method. 
In the controller method, use this Pojo object to retrieve those values.